# Can we implement six sigma on exponential distribution?

Tags: product-management, 6-sigma

As per my knowledge, if we can find the Defects-Per-Million-Opportunities from a Normal Distribution, then we can find the sigma level.

But if we have exponential distribution, how can we find the sigma level?

Comment: What’s six sigma and how does it relate to project management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where less known fact is applicable - six sigma does not have to be applicable to data with normal distribution. Or at least not raw data.

The answer you are looking for is in **[Central Limit Theorem](http://www.sixsigmatrainingfree.com/central-limit-theorem.html)**.

> The Central Limit Theorem is one of the cornerstones of lean six sigma and one of the first concepts understood in lean six sigma statistical training. We know that as we collect data from a process, the data points may or may not represent a normal distribution. However, when large enough (n>30) samples are drawn from any distribution, the distribution of the sample means approaches a normal one.

So in other words, you draw samples from your dataset and regardless of dataset distribution mean values of these samples will have normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The sigma level of a process is commonly used to describe the defect rate. This is why the central limit theorem is of no help for answering the question, because it describes the distribution of the *average value*, while we are interested in the scrap rate of the products.

One method is to transform the exponential dataset to become a normally distributed dataset. This is described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421559/how-to-change-exponential-distribution-into-normal-distribution). Once you have a normal distribution, you are allowed to use the standard calculations. However, I reckon that many people will have questions, and some will not accept this method. The arguments usually are based on the fact that your original distribution is not exactly exponential or that you only know the estimators of the distribution parameters, but not the exact population values.

An alternative method is to calculate the scrap rate using the exponential distribution. Say, we find a scrap rate of 2454ppm. Using the program language R, we find that this corresponds to a sigma level of 4.31:

```
## Define inputs:
ppm        = 1e-6
scrapRate0 = 2454*ppm
muShift    = 1.5 # we commonly use a shift of the average value to define the sigma level

## Define function calculating the DIFFERENCE between the theoretical scrap rate 
#  and the measured scrap rate: 
scrapRateFct = function(sigmaLevel){
    val        = pnorm(-sigmaLevel, muShift)+1-pnorm(sigmaLevel, muShift) 
    difference = val - scrapRate0
    return(difference)
}

##
# The root of the function defines the "solution":
sigmaLevel0 = 1 # initial guess
sigmaLevel  = pracma::fzero(fun=scrapRateFct, x=sigmaLevel0, maxiter=1e4, tol=1e-6 )

##
# Print result:
print(paste0("Sigma level: ", sigmaLevel$x))
scrapRate = pnorm(-sigmaLevel$x, muShift)+1-pnorm(sigmaLevel$x, muShift) 
print(paste0("Scrap rate: ", scrapRate/ppm))
```

Note that the average shift significantly influences the defect rate. Therefore, ensure that you report it correctly. E.g. if you evaluate short term studies, you should use muShift=0. In contrast, for a long term study you should use muShift=1.5, and report it accordingly.